# pdoc does not generate the function arguments as links

Tags: python, docstring, pdoc

I am using [pdoc3](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/) in order to generate my project docs.
The project is composed from 2 py modules:

- api.py
- model.py

The data structures are defined in model.py and used in api.py.

The generated HTML does not generate the function arguments as links.

How can I make pdoc generate the function args (data structures) as links?

==Code snippets==

api.py

```
def create_user(auth: Auth, user: User) -> CreateUserApiCallResult:
    """
    Create a User
    """
    return create_users(auth, [user])
```

model.py

```
@dataclass
class User:
    email: str
    inviteMessage: str
    accessGroups: List[str]
    profileData: ProfileData
```

Generated HTML

[image]

Comment: Can you show a small example code snippet of your functions and their args?

Comment: @K3---rnc Post was updated.

Answer (score 0):

> To produce HTML documentation of your whole package :

```
pdoc --html --output-dir build my_package
```

[documentation of pdoc3](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/doc/pdoc/#command-line-interface)

It will create the links if there is no importation error.